Action of Isotropy group on hyperbolic spaces
Let $\mathbb R^{n,1}$ be the space  $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ endowed with the bilinear form $$\langle x, y \rangle_{n,1} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_iy_i -x_{n+1}y_{n+1}$$   We define the hyperboloid model  as $$\mathbb{H}^n = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+2} \mid \langle x, x\rangle_{n,1} = -1, x_{n+1}>0\}$$
We define  $$O(n, 1) = \{A \in GL(n+1, \mathbb{R}) \mid \langle Ax, Ay \rangle_{n,1} = \langle x, y \rangle_{n,1} \ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\}$$ We define $$O^+(n, 1) = \{A \in O(n,1)) \mid A(\mathbb{H}^n) = \mathbb{H}^n\}$$ and $\text{Isom}\ (\mathbb{H}^n) = O^+(n,1)$. Also, $\text{Isotropy}(O^+(n,1), e_{n+1})= \begin{bmatrix}O(n)&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$
I want to prove that for if $T \in \text{Isom} \mathbb{H}^n$ then there exist $L \in \text{Isotropy}(O^+(n,1), e_{n+1})$ such that $L^{-1}T(e_{n+1}) = (0, \cdots, \sinh t, \cosh t)$.
My approach: Since $\text{Isom} \mathbb H^n$ acts transitively on $\mathbb H^n$ then use rotations $$\begin{bmatrix}U&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ where $U \in O(n)$  to move $T(e_{n+1})$ in the $e_n$-$e_{n+1}$-plane. Since $\text{Isotropy}(O^+(n,1), e_{n+1})$ acts transitively on $2$-dimensional linear subspaces of $T_{e_{n+1}} \mathbb H^n$, there is $L$ such that $L^{-1}T(e_{n+1}) = (0, \cdots, \sinh t, \cosh t)$.
Is my solution correct?
